# Retrieve and use volley error HTTP response code with switch case to handle error

Tags: json, error-handling, switch-statement, android-volley

I want to put error response code in switch statement where I am handling the various error cases.How can I fetch the response code from `VolleyErros`.

**Error:**

> E/Volley: [205] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 409 for https://api.abc.com:3211/newuser

```
new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            if(error != null && error.getMessage() != null)
            {
                Log.e("Response error", error.getMessage());
            }
            switch (error.toString()){
                case "409" : errorBox.setText("username already exists");
                    break;
                case "410" : errorBox.setText("email already exists");
                    break;
                case "411" : errorBox.setText("xyz already exists");
                    break;
                case "413" : errorBox.setText("abc already exists");
                    break;
                case "414" : errorBox.setText("username invalid ");
                    break;
                default :
                    Log.d(TAG, "onErrorResponse: "+error.toString());
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**P.S.:** Switch should process *only* < **409** > the response code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `statusCode` which is an int. [docs](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/com/android/volley/NetworkResponse.java)

```
  new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if(error != null && error.getMessage() != null)
                {
                    Log.e("Response error", error.getMessage());
                }
                switch (error.networkResponse.statusCode){
                    case 409 : errorBox.setText("username already exists");
                        break;
                    case 410 : errorBox.setText("email already exists");
                        break;
                    case 411 : errorBox.setText("xyz already exists");
                        break;
                    case 413 : errorBox.setText("abc already exists");
                        break;
                    case 414 : errorBox.setText("username invalid ");
                        break;
                    default :
                        Log.d(TAG, "onErrorResponse: "+error.toString());
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

You should also put a nullity check to verify the 'networkResponse' is not null.

```
if(error.networkResponse!= null){
  // switch code
}
```